How to Optimize Bulk Insert of Related Records in Entity Framework Core Without Using EFCore.BulkExtensions?
I am working on a project where I need to insert a large number of related records into multiple tables using Entity Framework Core. The insertion process involves at least three tables: Question, QuestionAnswer, and MultimediaQuestion (if the question has an image). Additionally, if the question is requested against any exam, a fourth table insertion into ExamQuestion is required.
When inserting 1 or 2 records, the process works fine as each record is inserted one by one. However, when bulk uploading around 400 records via excel, the process takes a considerable amount of time. I need to optimize this bulk insert process, but I am not sure how to achieve this without optimizing the code itself.
I am using MySQL database and the project is on.NET6
Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Constraints:
I cannot use the EFCore.BulkExtensions library as it is a paid solution.
The Question table has a long question_id, and adding all questions to the context will not auto-generate question_id.
Here is a summary of my current approach and the issues I am facing:
Insert record into Question table.
Insert associated records into QuestionAnswer table.
If the question has an image, insert records into MultimediaQuestion table.
If the question is requested against any exam, insert records into ExamQuestion table.
Questions:
What are the best practices for optimizing bulk inserts in Entity Framework Core without using paid libraries?
Are there any alternative approaches or libraries that I can use to improve the performance of bulk inserts?
How can I handle the auto-generation of question_id efficiently in this bulk insert scenario?

Is part of the sluggishness caused by needing to retrieve AUTO_INCREMENT values?  Can you provide the generated SQL so we can study the issues from MySQL point of view?
